# Torchvision Datasets: Flickr8k not importing Datapoints correctly

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, kaggle, torchvision

I am using torchvision.Datasets to import Flickr8k for later usage inside a Jupyter Notebook. I downloaded all Images from Kaggle into a Folder "archive/Images" and have the file "captions.txt" inside the "archive" Folder. Below is the Problem, the Images and Captions are not loaded and can not be reached for printing or data-loading.

How can i solve this problem?

Versions:

```
conda            : 4.10.1
jupyter core     : 4.6.3
jupyter-notebook : 6.1.4
torch            : 1.7.1+cu110
torchvision      : 0.8.2+cu110
```

Code:

```
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torchvision.datasets import Flickr8k

transform = transforms.Compose(
[transforms.ToTensor(),
 transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])

trainset=Flickr8k(root='~/archive/Images', ann_file='~/archive/captions.txt', transform=transform)
print(trainset)
```

Expected Behaviour:

```
Dataset Flickr8k
Number of datapoints: 40.000
Root location: ~/archive/Images
```

Real Behaviour:

```
Dataset Flickr8k
Number of datapoints: 0
Root location: ~/archive/Images
```

Comment: ran into same issue on google colab. Did you fix it?